# Finding WiFi Password that is stored in Laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a laptop with Windows 7. My home has a few WiFi networks, and, for some reason, no one knows the passwords. The laptop can connect to those networks, however.

So, I thought that the laptop must have the passwords stored somewhere in its registry.

Is this true? Can I obtain those passwords?

Comment: Right click the WiFi icon in system tray--> Open Network & Sharing Center -->Manage Wireless Networks --> Right click your network --> Properties -->Security Tab -->Check Show Characters

Comment: [How to Recover Stored Wi-Fi Passwords (Security Key) in Windows?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/recover-wifi-password-stored-key/)

Comment: @pat2015 Thanks! That's awesome.